# Docker-compose: node_modules not present in a volume after npm install succeeds

Tags: node.js, docker, ubuntu-14.04, docker-compose

I have an app with the following services:

- `web/` - holds and runs a python 3 flask web server on port 5000. Uses sqlite3.
- `worker/` - has an `index.js` file which is a worker for a queue. the web server interacts with this queue using a json API over port `9730`. The worker uses redis for storage. The worker also stores data locally in the folder `worker/images/`

Now this question only concerns the `worker`.

#### `worker/Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:0.12

WORKDIR /worker

COPY package.json /worker/
RUN npm install

COPY . /worker/
```

#### `docker-compose.yml`

```
redis:
    image: redis
worker:
    build: ./worker
    command: npm start
    ports:
        - "9730:9730"
    volumes:
        - worker/:/worker/
    links:
        - redis
```

When I run `docker-compose build`, everything works as expected and all npm modules are installed in `/worker/node_modules` as I'd expect.

```
npm WARN package.json unfold@1.0.0 No README data

> phantomjs@1.9.2-6 install /worker/node_modules/pageres/node_modules/screenshot-stream/node_modules/phantom-bridge/node_modules/phantomjs
> node install.js

<snip>
```

But when I do `docker-compose up`, I see this error:

```
worker_1 | Error: Cannot find module 'async'
worker_1 |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
worker_1 |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
worker_1 |     at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
worker_1 |     at require (module.js:384:17)
worker_1 |     at Object.<anonymous> (/worker/index.js:1:75)
worker_1 |     at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
worker_1 |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
worker_1 |     at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
worker_1 |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
worker_1 |     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
```

Turns out none of the modules are present in `/worker/node_modules` (on host or in the container).

If on the host, I `npm install`, then everything works just fine. But I don't want to do that. I want the container to handle dependencies.

What's going wrong here?

(Needless to say, all packages are in `package.json`.)

Comment: I think you should use the ONBUILD instruction... Like this: https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/master/0.12/onbuild/Dockerfile#L6

Comment: How would you do development on the host when the IDE does not know the node_module dependencies?

Comment: Try to remove `volumes: - worker/:/worker/` block from `docker-compose.yml` file. This line overwrite the folder you make with COPY command.

Comment: `When I run docker-compose build, everything works as expected and all npm modules are installed in /worker/node_modules as I'd expect.` - How did you check this?

Comment: @Vallie you can watch content of image you built with "docker build" using "docker run -it image_name sh"

Answer (score 443):

This happens because you have added your `worker` directory as a volume to your `docker-compose.yml`, as the volume is not mounted during the build.

When docker builds the image, the `node_modules` directory is created within the `worker` directory, and all the dependencies are installed there. Then on runtime the `worker` directory from outside docker is mounted into the docker instance (which does not have the installed `node_modules`), hiding the `node_modules` you just installed. You can verify this by removing the mounted volume from your `docker-compose.yml`.

A workaround is to use a data volume to store all the `node_modules`, as data volumes copy in the data from the built docker image before the `worker` directory is mounted. This can be done in the `docker-compose.yml` like this:

```yaml
redis:
    image: redis
worker:
    build: ./worker
    command: npm start
    ports:
        - "9730:9730"
    volumes:
        - ./worker/:/worker/
        - /worker/node_modules
    links:
        - redis
```

I'm not entirely certain whether this imposes any issues for the portability of the image, but as it seems you are primarily using docker to provide a runtime environment, this should not be an issue.

If you want to read more about volumes, there is a nice user guide available here: https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/

EDIT: Docker has since changed it's syntax to require a leading `./` for mounting in files relative to the docker-compose.yml file.

Comment: is it possible to also mount a local node_module to this setup? For example, I want to locally debug 1 specific node_module, can I add `worker/node_modules/locally-installed-module:/worker/node-modules/locally-installed-module`? I have tried this but it does not seem to work.

Comment: @mattgi: Yes and no, It's not possible without also changing your run command. If you remove the additional volume, such that your `docker-compose.yml` becomes like the one in the original question (it should also work with the volume you mentioned), and you also have to run your `npm install` as part of your docker command, as the volume won't be mounted until the container actually starts.

Comment: I've tried this method and hit the wall when dependencies changed. I've rebuilt the image, started new container and volume `/worker/node_modules` stayed the same as before (with old dependencies). Is there any trick how to use new volume upon rebuilding the image?

Comment: It seems docker compose doesn't remove volumes if other containers use them (even if they are dead). So if there are some dead containers of the same type (for whatever reason) the scenario I've described in previous comment follows. From what I've tried, using `docker-compose rm` seem to fix this problem, but I believe there must be a better and easier solution.

Comment: The proposal of double volume `node_modules:/worker/node_modules` doesn't work either ... :(

Comment: Is there a solution in 2018 without having to `rebuild --no-cache` everytime the deps change?

Comment: you need to rebuild if the package installation is done on building time (like the question does). This is because docker creates a layer for that and you will run your app over that layer. It's annoying if you need to change your packages a frequently? yes but clean

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the node_modules folder is not accessible from your development machine (outside the container)

Comment: you can now use [` --renew-anon-volumes`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/) which will recreate anonymous volumes instead of data from the previous containers.

Comment: This solution works well. However, for those who did everything but it didn't work, try to delete all caches and docker images that you made. I hope this would be helpful for someone. It's been discussed above.

Comment: @FrederikNS can you pls look this question i am facing similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68281301/docker-compose-node-modules-is-not-present-in-docker-volume

Comment: None of this worked after adding dependencies. The only way so far was to manually delete the volume with `docker volume rm` and rebuild the containers.

Comment: Its 2023, do we not have a solution for nodejs apps in a container to be able to just build the image and develop it on any machine, with dependencies and everything just working?

Comment: In my case, I did the opposite. I had `.:app` and `app/node_modules` under volumes. Removing `app/node_modules` resolved the issue

Answer (score 61):

The `node_modules` folder is overwritten by the volume and no more accessible in the container. I'm using the [native module loading strategy](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders) to take out the folder from the volume:

```
/data/node_modules/ # dependencies installed here
/data/app/ # code base
```

Dockerfile:

```
COPY package.json /data/
WORKDIR /data/
RUN npm install
ENV PATH /data/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY . /data/app/
WORKDIR /data/app/
```

The `node_modules` directory is not accessible from outside the container because it is included in the image.

Comment: `node_modules` is not accessible from outside of container but not really a downside ;)

Comment: and every time you change package.json you need to rebuild the whole container with --no-cache right?

Comment: You need to rebuild the image when you change package.json, yes, but --no-cache is not necessary. If you run `docker-compose run app npm install` you will create an node_modules in the current directory and you don't need to rebuild the image anymore.

Comment: The downside is: no more IDE autocompletion, no help, no good dev experience. Everything also needs to be installed on the host now, but isn't the reason for using docker here that the dev-host needs nothing to be able to work with a project?

Comment: wonderful and simple solution. makes containers so much more portable for anyone to just docker-compose up. Thanks for this

Answer (score 60):

The solution provided by @FrederikNS works, but I prefer to explicitly name my node_modules volume.

My `project/docker-compose.yml` file (docker-compose version 1.6+) :

```
version: '2'
services:
  frontend:
    ....
    build: ./worker
    volumes:
      - ./worker:/worker
      - node_modules:/worker/node_modules
    ....
volumes:
  node_modules:
```

my file structure is :

```
project/
   │── worker/
   │     └─ Dockerfile
   └── docker-compose.yml
```

It creates a volume named `project_node_modules` and re-use it every time I up my application.

My `docker volume ls` looks like this :

```
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               project_mysql
local               project_node_modules
local               project2_postgresql
local               project2_node_modules
```

Comment: while this “works”, you’re circumventing a real concept in docker: all dependencies shoud be baked in for maximum portability. you cannot move this image without running other commands which kinda blows

Comment: @JavierBuzzi the problem is that npm/yarn's node_modules are at odds with that philosophy. If you don't have plug'n'play set up in your app then you need to do it this way. There's also $NODE_PATH but I couldn't get it to work for my use-case. This works fine for me. It's also no different than the top-voted answer other than using named volumes vs. anonymous ones.

Answer (score 39):

I recently had a similar problem. You can install `node_modules` elsewhere and set the `NODE_PATH` environment variable.

In the example below I installed `node_modules` into `/install`

### worker/Dockerfile

```
FROM node:0.12

RUN ["mkdir", "/install"]

ADD ["./package.json", "/install"]
WORKDIR /install
RUN npm install --verbose
ENV NODE_PATH=/install/node_modules

WORKDIR /worker

COPY . /worker/
```

### docker-compose.yml

```
redis:
    image: redis
worker:
    build: ./worker
    command: npm start
    ports:
        - "9730:9730"
    volumes:
        - worker/:/worker/
    links:
        - redis
```

Comment: The top voted solution by @FrederikNS is useful, was how I solved a different issue of my local volume overwriting the container's `node_modules` based on [this article](http://jdlm.info/articles/2016/03/06/lessons-building-node-app-docker.html). But it led me to experience [this issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4337).

This solution here of creating a separate directory to copy your `package.json` to, run `npm install` there, then specify the `NODE_PATH` environment variable in `docker-compose.yml` to point to the `node_modules` folder of that directory works and feels right.

Comment: Installing the node modules to a different path (/install) then setting the NODE_PATH (ENV NODE_PATH=/install/node_modules) solves the problem as the path doesn't get overridden after a volume mount.

Answer (score 24):

There's elegant solution:

Just mount not whole directory, but only app directory. This way you'll you won't have troubles with `npm_modules`.

Example:

```
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./ui_frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
    - 3000:3000
    volumes:
    - ./ui_frontend/src:/frontend/src
```

Dockerfile.dev:

```
FROM node:7.2.0

#Show colors in docker terminal
ENV COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT=50000
ENV TERM="xterm-256color"

COPY . /frontend
WORKDIR /frontend
RUN npm install update
RUN npm install --global typescript
RUN npm install --global webpack
RUN npm install --global webpack-dev-server
RUN npm install --global karma protractor
RUN npm install
CMD npm run server:dev
```

Comment: This is good and fast solution but it requires rebuilds & prunes after new dependency installation.

Answer (score 17):

## UPDATE: Use the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32785014/2228916) provided by @FrederikNS.

I encountered the same problem. When the folder `/worker` is mounted to the container - all of it's content will be syncronized (so the node_modules folder will disappear if you don't have it locally.)

Due to incompatible npm packages based on OS, I could not just install the modules locally - then launch the container, so..

My solution to this, was to wrap the source in a `src` folder, then link `node_modules` into that folder, using [this index.js file](https://gist.github.com/jmyrland/eaeef7b794c41ec1af9d). So, the `index.js` file is now the starting point of my application.

When I run the container, I mounted the `/app/src` folder to my local `src` folder.

So the container folder looks something like this:

```
/app
  /node_modules
  /src
    /node_modules -> ../node_modules
    /app.js
  /index.js
```

It is **ugly**, but it works..

Answer (score 12):

Due to [the way Node.js loads modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders), `node_modules` can be anywhere in the path to your source code. For example, put your source at `/worker/src` and your `package.json` in `/worker`, so `/worker/node_modules` is where they're installed.

Answer (score 9):

There is also some simple solution without mapping `node_module` directory into another volume. It's about to move installing npm packages into final CMD command.

> Disadvantage of this approach:
>
> - run `npm install` each time you run container (switching from `npm` to `yarn` might also speed up this process a bit).

#### worker/Dockerfile

```
FROM node:0.12
WORKDIR /worker
COPY package.json /worker/
COPY . /worker/
CMD /bin/bash -c 'npm install; npm start'
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```
redis:
    image: redis
worker:
    build: ./worker
    ports:
        - "9730:9730"
    volumes:
        - worker/:/worker/
    links:
        - redis
```

Answer (score 8):

Installing node_modules in container to different from project folder, and setting NODE_PATH to your node_modules folder helps me (u need to rebuild container).

I'm using docker-compose. My project file structure:

```
-/myproject
--docker-compose.yml
--nodejs/
----Dockerfile
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  nodejs:
    image: myproject/nodejs
    build: ./nodejs/.
    volumes:
      - ./nodejs:/workdir
    ports:
      - "23005:3000"
    command: npm run server
```

Dockerfile in nodejs folder:

```
FROM node:argon
RUN mkdir /workdir
COPY ./package.json /workdir/.
RUN mkdir /data
RUN ln -s /workdir/package.json /data/.
WORKDIR /data
RUN npm install
ENV NODE_PATH /data/node_modules/
WORKDIR /workdir
```

Answer (score 5):

There are two seperate requirements I see for node dev environments... mount your source code INTO the container, and mount the node_modules FROM the container (for your IDE).  To accomplish the first, you do the usual mount, but not everything... just the things you need

```
volumes:
    - worker/src:/worker/src
    - worker/package.json:/worker/package.json
    - etc...
```

( the reason to not do `- /worker/node_modules` is because docker-compose will persist that volume between runs, meaning you can diverge from what is actually in the image (defeating the purpose of not just bind mounting from your host)).

The second one is actually harder.  My solution is a bit hackish, but it works.  I have a script to install the node_modules folder on my host machine, and I just have to remember to call it whenever I update package.json (or, add it to the make target that runs docker-compose build locally).

```
install_node_modules:
    docker build -t building .
    docker run -v `pwd`/node_modules:/app/node_modules building npm install
```

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, we should not `RUN npm install` in the Dockerfile. Instead, we can start a container using bash to install the dependencies before runing the formal node service

```
docker run -it -v ./app:/usr/src/app  your_node_image_name  /bin/bash
root@247543a930d6:/usr/src/app# npm install
```

Comment: I actually agree with you on this one. Volumes are meant to be used when you want to share the data between container and host. When you decide to have your `node_modules` be persistent even after container remove, you should also know when or when not to do a `npm install` manually. OP suggests to do it *on every image build*. You can do that, but you don't need to also use a volume for that. On every build, the modules will be up to date anywys.

Comment: @Blauhirn it's helpful to mount a local host volume into the container when doing e.g. gulp watch (or analogous commands) - you want the node_modules to persist while still allowing changes to other sources (js, css etc). npm insists on using a local gulp, so it has to persist (or be installed via other methods on start-up)

Answer (score 4):

You can also ditch your Dockerfile, because of its simplicity, just use a basic image and specify the command in your compose file:

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  frontend:
    image: node:12-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/:/app/
    command: sh -c "cd /app/ && yarn && yarn run start"
    expose: [8080]
    ports:
      - 8080:4200
```

This is particularly useful for me, because I just need the environment of the image, but operate on my files outside the container and I think this is what you want to do too.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I spent 3 days trying to find out why the hell is `node_modules` directory not being synchronized because I wanted the exact same thing you wrote. When I removed the `- /app/node_modules` volume, my `npm run start` command wouldn't run because I got `sh: react-scripts: not found`, even though the dependencies were installed, and I was going nuts over it.
It does take a while to start, but whatever, at least it does what I need, and it's for development only.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the `node_modules` folder available to the host during development, you could install the dependencies when you start the container instead of during build-time. I do this to get syntax highlighting working in my editor.

#### Dockerfile

```
# We're using a multi-stage build so that we can install dependencies during build-time only for production.

# dev-stage
FROM node:14-alpine AS dev-stage
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json ./
COPY . .
# `yarn install` will run every time we start the container. We're using yarn because it's much faster than npm when there's nothing new to install
CMD ["sh", "-c", "yarn install && yarn run start"]

# production-stage
FROM node:14-alpine AS production-stage
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json ./
RUN yarn install
COPY . .
```

#### .dockerignore

Add `node_modules` to `.dockerignore` to prevent it from being copied when the `Dockerfile` runs `COPY . .`. We use volumes to bring in `node_modules`.

```
**/node_modules
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```yaml
node_app:
    container_name: node_app
    build:
        context: ./node_app
        target: dev-stage # `production-stage` for production
    volumes:
        # For development:
        #   If node_modules already exists on the host, they will be copied
        #   into the container here. Since `yarn install` runs after the
        #   container starts, this volume won't override the node_modules.
        - ./node_app:/usr/src/app
        # For production:
        #   
        - ./node_app:/usr/src/app
        - /usr/src/app/node_modules
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just move `node_modules` into a `/` folder.

[How it works](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders)

```
FROM node:0.12

WORKDIR /worker

COPY package.json /worker/
RUN npm install \
  && mv node_modules /node_modules

COPY . /worker/
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this in your Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:0.12
WORKDIR /worker
CMD bash ./start.sh
```

Then you should use the Volume like this:

```
volumes:
  - worker/:/worker:rw
```

The startscript should be a part of your worker repository and looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
npm install
npm start
```

So the node_modules are a part of your worker volume and gets synchronized and the npm scripts are executed when everything is up.

Comment: This will add a large overhead to starting up the container.

Comment: But only the first time because the node_modules will be persisted on the local machine.

Comment: Or until the image is rebuilt, or the volume removed :) . That said, I've not found a better solution myself.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the most popular answers on this page but ran into an issue: the `node_modules` directory in my Docker instance would get cached in the the named or unnamed mount point, and later would overwrite the `node_modules` directory that was built as part of the Docker build process. Thus, new modules I added to `package.json` would not show up in the Docker instance.

Fortunately I found this excellent page which explains what was going on and gives at least 3 ways to work around it:
https://burnedikt.com/dockerized-node-development-and-mounting-node-volumes/

Comment: To make your answer more complete please document the solution you used along with at least some of the code you used to make it work.

Comment: this link does not exists anymore but i copy/pasted it on wayback machine lol

Answer (score 1):

**If you don't use docker-compose** you can do it like this:

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli

COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ng serve --port 5000 --host 0.0.0.0
```

Then you build it: `docker build -t myname .` and you run it by **adding two volumes**, the second one without source: `docker run --rm -it -p 5000:5000 -v "$PWD":/usr/src/app/ -v /usr/src/app/node_modules myname`

Comment: I cannot tell you how much time I wasted before coming to your answer. Fantastic - I can go to be now. Thank you thank you thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With Yarn you can move the node_modules outside the volume by setting

```
# ./.yarnrc
--modules-folder /opt/myproject/node_modules
```

See https://www.caxy.com/blog/how-set-custom-location-nodemodules-path-yarn

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [FrederikNS's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32785014/5601560):

**Newly installed npm packages will not end up in the container after rebuild and restart.**

To solve this run:

```bash
docker compose build --no-cache
docker compose up --force-recreate -V # <--- Notice the -V flag
```

The -V flag removes anonymous volumes.

```yaml
volumes:
   - ./worker/:/worker/
   - /worker/node_modules
```

When using a data volumes (Or anonymous volumes) Docker copies the node_modules folder from the built docker image to a anonymous volume.

However anonymous volumes persist between builds and restarts. So the newly installed package ends up in your container when building, but because the anonymous volume still contains the old node_modules contents this is overlayed in the container, thus hiding the new node_modules.

The -V flag deletes anonymous volumes and then a new anonymous volume is recreated from the docker container, with the newly installed package.

I created a make file that has all the docker commands that i need, so that every time I need to make changes to packages, I don't forget to add the -V flag to bring the container up again. No all I need to do is run

```bash
npm install <package>
make build
make up
```

and the package is installed, the containers are rebuild and the containers are restarted with a newly created anonymous volume with my newly installed packages.

```
COMPOSE_FILE := docker-compose.yml

# Base docker compose command
DC := docker compose -f $(COMPOSE_FILE)

.PHONY: build up

# Main targets
build:
    $(DC) build --no-cache

up:
    $(DC) up -d -V --force-recreate
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to overcome this issue of `client` container NOT finding/ NOT having node_modules is the following:

Build a **frontend** and push it to dockerhub that can run **on its own.**

So when you do `docker-compose up` for your backend and db, it'll pull your frontend image from your specified dockerhub repo.
In this way, the nodemodules issue is not a problem because your frontend container is already running separately and your are just pulling that in your `docker-compose.yml`

Example directory structure:

```
my-app/
-docker-compose.yml
-- backend/
-- client/
-------Dockerfile
```

And in your `docker-compose.yml`, you simply specify the build like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  frontend:
    image: <your-docker-frontend-rep>/<project>:tag
```

I am still a new to docker, please feel free to comment if i'm wrong. TY.