# Docker compose volume mapping with NodeJS app

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to achieve something incredibly basic, but have been going at this for a couple of evenings now and still haven't found a solid (or any) solution. I have found some similar topics on SO and followed what was on there but to no avail, so I have created a GitHub repo for my specific case.

What I'm trying to do:

- Be able to provision NodeJS app using `docker-compose up -d` (I plan to add further containers in future, omitted from this example)
- Ensure the code is mapped via `volumes` so I don't have to re-build every time I make a change to some code locally.

My guess is the issue I'm encountering is something to do with the mapping of `volumes` causing some files to be lost/overwritten within the container, for instance in some of the variations I've tried the folders are being mapped but individual files are not.

I've created a simple repo to illustrate my issue, just checkout and run  `docker-compose up -d` to see the issue, the container dies due to:

`Error: Cannot find module '/src/app/app.js'`

The link to the repo is here: https://github.com/josephmcdermott/nodejs-docker-issue, PR's welcome and if anybody can solve this for me I'd be eternally grateful.

**UPDATE: please see the solution code below, kind thanks to ldg**

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:4.4.7

RUN mkdir -p /src
COPY . /src
WORKDIR /src
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node", "/src/app.js"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
app:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - ./app:/src/app
```

Folder Structure:

```
- app
- - * (files I want to sync and regularly update)
- app.js (initial script to call files within app/)
- Dockerfile
- docker-compose.yml
- package.json
```

Comment: Fyi, your code is short enough you could post (at least the relevant parts) here (which is encouraged over simply linking).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your compose file, the last line `- /src/app/node_modules` is likely mapping over your previous volume. If you mount /scr/app then node_modules will get created in that linked volume. So it would look like this:

```
app:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - ./app:/src/app
```

If you do want to keep your entire `/app` directory as a linked volume, you'll need to either do `npm install` when starting the container (which would insure it picks up any updates) OR **don't link** the volume and update your Dockerfile to copy the entire `/app` directory. This is nice because it gives you a self-contained image. I usually Dockerize my Node.js apps this way. You can also run `npm test` as appropriate to verify the image.

If you need to create a linked volume for a script file you want to be able to edit (or if your app generates side-effects), you can link just that directory or file via Docker volumes.

Btw, if you want to make sure you don't copy the contents of that directory in the future, add it to .[dockerignore](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/dockerignore-file) (as well as .gitignore).

Comment: Hi ldg, thank you for your response.

I've tried your suggestions and I can get the 'self contained' image working fine as long as I don't include any volumes in docker-compose.yml, but as soon as I try to map a directory for easy development it 'disappears'.

I have committed the latest to the same github repository (I wanted to use the github repo rather than pasting code in here as I knew I would be making changes like this, and the diff could be useful).

The latest version I get `Error: Cannot find module './app/someFile.js'`

Comment: It works for me now. Can you try a fresh install and if you still get errors, outline the steps?

Comment: The local vs external is more about helping others. From http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask: "...create a live example of the problem that you can link to then do so - but also include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time."

Comment: "It works for me now" - yes, you are correct, I must have missed a build when I tried last. Many thanks for your support ldg and your comment re: local vs external makes sense, I will update the original question with the correct code.

Answer (score -1):

Notice the '/' at the end

```
volumes:
    - ./app:/src/app/
```

This declaration is not correct

```
volumes:
    - ./app:/src/app
```