# How to exclude some paths when mounting the volume?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I would like to mount everything inside my current directory, except `/node_modules` and `/client/bower_components`. I currently have to manually mount all the paths as following:

```
app:
  build: .
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
    - "35729:35729"
  links:
    - mongo
  volumes:
    - client/app:/www/app/client/app
    - client/assets:/www/app/client/assets
    - client/components:/www/app/client/components
    - server:/www/app/server
    ...
mongo:
  image: mongo
  ports:
    - "27017:27017"
```

Is there somehow I can exclude some paths, for example `!client/bower_components` and `!node_modules`?

Comment: You can find a solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29181032/add-a-volume-to-docker-but-exclude-a-sub-folder

Comment: @impactmass, Specifically the solution can be find in https://stackoverflow.com/a/37898591/1875049

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a volume to Docker, but exclude a sub-folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29181032/add-a-volume-to-docker-but-exclude-a-sub-folder)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.

There are answers to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30043872/docker-compose-node-modules-not-present-in-a-volume-after-npm-install-succeeds) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29181032/add-a-volume-to-docker-but-exclude-a-sub-folder).

For quick reference, the solution is below.

```yaml
volumes:
  - ./parent:/usr/share/elasticsearch/parent
  - /usr/share/elasticsearch/parent/node_modules/
```

Here are the [docker volume docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)