# How to sync back files from a Docker container to its host?

Tags: linux, node.js, windows, docker, vagrant

Maybe I am overcomplicating this.

My goal is to create a Docker-based workflow on Windows for Node.js application development.

1. In development time, I'd be able to run my app locally inside a container and still see the latest version without too much hassle (I don't want to rebuild the image everytime to see the latest).
2. On the other hand, when I deploy to production, I want to have my source files "baked" into the container image with all the dependencies (`npm install`)

So I created two Vagrantfiles - one for the container and one for its host. Here's an extract of the latter:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.provider "docker" do |docker|
    docker.vagrant_vagrantfile = "host/Vagrantfile"  # it references the host Vagrantfile
    docker.build_dir = "."  # we have a Dockerfile in the same dir
    docker.create_args = ['--volume="/usr/src/host:/usr/src/appcontainer:rw"']
  end
end
```

`/usr/src/host` is a directory which contains all of my source code (without `node_modules`). During the build of the `Dockerfile`, Docker copies the `package.json` to `/usr/src/appcontainer` and issues an `npm install` there which is fine for my second requirement (deploy to production)

But my first requirement was to change the source during development, so I mounted `/usr/src/appcontainer` as a volume pointing to the host directory `/usr/src/host`. However, this is not working, because `/usr/src/host` doesn't have a `node_modules` folder - this folder only exists in the container.

This whole problem seems to be easy - changing a file under Windows, see its changing both under the Linux host VM and in its container and vica versa... But I've got a bit stuck.

What is the best practice to achieve this syncing behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, this is not working, because /usr/src/host doesn't have a node_modules folder

You can use one of the approaches described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30043872/6309), for instance by using a data volume dedicated for `node_modules`.
Or mounting the host `node_modules` as a separate folder within the container.