# Docker-Compose volume syntax with source folder missing

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mounted-volumes

I am struggling to understand the following syntax in docker-compose yml for the volumes.

```
cache:
  build: ../../
  dockerfile: docker/dev/Dockerfile
  volumes:
    - /tmp/cache:/cache
    - /build
  entrypoint: "true"
```

The first volume */cache* is clearly mounted to physical folder */tmp/cache* on the host. Where is it mounted the second one */build* instead? I could not find good references.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second volume will be what is described as an *anonymous* volume. Usually they live under the `/var/lib/docker` directory, unless you have made a different configuration.

I believe you will find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44976571/docker-anonymous-volumes) anwser useful.

Answer (score 1):

With one path this is a "anonymous" volume. Docker will create that value for you. You can [read more here](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2019/07/11/docker-volumes-explained/)