# How can I add Svelte to my docker container with Django?

Tags: django, docker, svelte, sveltekit

I have managed to create a docker and get running a django project.

I realised, a lot of tutorials and answers to problems on different websites don't mention the real folder tree so when people need to figure out volumes and routes, it is extremely difficult to understand what is related to what

This is my folder tree
[image]

This is the Dockerfile for DJANGO

```
FROM python:3.12-slim-bullseye

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./app /app

RUN adduser --disabled-login user
USER user
```

and this is the dockercompose for DJANGO

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=XXXXX
      - POSTGRES_USER=XXX
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=XXX
  
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py collectstatic --noinput &&
             python manage.py migrate &&
             python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:XXXX"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    ports:
      - "XXXXX"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_NAME=XXXXX
      - POSTGRES_USER=XXXXXX
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=XXXXX
    depends_on:
      - db
```

What do I need to modify to be able to add Svelte in the same docker?

And what if I wanted to add SvelteKit?

I saw something about multistage builds but I don't fully understand it

UPDATE 28.10.2023

I tried to implement Svelte independently but it is not working. I'm getting the error "sh: 1: vite: not found"

Svelte docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    # The name of the image that will be created when building this container
    image: frontend
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./app-frontend:/app-frontend
      - /app-frontend/node_modules
    user: "node"
    environment:
      # Internal server error messages will not send stacktrace to the browser in production
      - NODE_ENV=production
    # Points to a file with the sensitive environment variables
    env_file:
      - .env
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 3000:5050
```

Svelte Dockerfile

```
# Use this image as the platform to build the app
FROM node:21 AS frontend

#Establish the environment
ENV NODE_ENV=production

#Create the folder and give it permissions
RUN mkdir -p /app-frontend
RUN chmod -R 777 /app-frontend

# The WORKDIR instruction sets the working directory for everything that will happen next
WORKDIR /app-frontend

# Copy all local files into the image
COPY ./app-frontend /app-frontend

RUN npm install

# Clean install all node modules
RUN npm ci

# remove potential security issues
RUN npm audit fix

# Build SvelteKit app
RUN npm run build

# Delete source code files that were used to build the app that are no longer needed
RUN rm -rf src/ static/ emailTemplates/ docker-compose.yml

# The USER instruction sets the user name to use as the default user for the remainder of the current stage
USER node:node

# This is the command that will be run inside the image when you tell Docker to start the container
CMD ["node","build/index.js"]
```

.env file

```
# Environment variables.
STATUS=production
HOST=0.0.0.0
#Development port
DEV_PORT=4173
#Production port
PROD_PORT=5173
```

I reckon something is wrong with the volumes and the routes but I can't find what and the information on internet is very diverse

Comment: Do you want to use Svelte from within Django templates or do you want to have a standalone web application that connects to the Django backend?

Comment: The idea is to be able to deploy both with one dockerfile. I updated the OP with information about my folder tree and what I would like to achieve

Comment: Please see here an example how to run [SvelteKit frontend](https://medium.com/coinmonks/merkle-tree-a-simple-explanation-and-implementation-48903442bc08) with [Python backend using Caddy](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/proxy-server/blob/195510dbfdc7c7da4ab876e6fe77116d706819c5/Caddyfile#L25). Three containers: frontend, backend, reverse proxy server. But all this could be run in the same container. Effectively SvelteKit and Django need their own URL mappings/paths/domains for the same server.

Comment: You want Node.js adapter / Express server deployment for your frontend and it may also act as a proxy for your backend, but unfortunately I do not know how to configure Express.js server to proxy Django.

Comment: Also the main benefit of running your frontend in a different container is that if your backend goes down, SvelteKit may still serve you the landing page and some static pages of the website.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your docker build is failing with this message

> sh: 1: vite: not found

is because you are using `NODE_ENV=production` which causes `npm install` to skip any `devDependencies`, but in your `package.json` `vite` is listed as a `devDependency`, so the `npm run build` will fail.

One approach would be to split the Dockerfile into two stages:

1. First stage where you execute `npm run build`
2. Second stage where you copy the build artifacts from stage 1 and run the application

This would look something like this:

```
FROM node:21-alpine AS build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm ci
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
RUN npm prune --production

FROM node:21-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-stage /app/build build/
COPY --from=build-stage /app/node_modules node_modules/
COPY package.json .
EXPOSE 3000
ENV NODE_ENV=production
CMD [ "node", "build" ]
```

Comment: Thanks a million. Should I change the environment or should I change package.json?

The Dockerfile is used in my laptop so I can develop the app. What should I need to change in the future if I want to deploy this? Any additional information is appreciated

Comment: Updated the answer with a suggestion

Comment: Bear in mind Django is using WORKDIR /app as well.
Would this mount the frontend app on top of Django?

Could you please have in consideration the folder tree from the OP above in your answer?
Thanks, this is really helpful.

Also, before you posted this, I removed the production environment from the env file and the Dockerfile and I got this error:
Error: Cannot find module '/app-frontend/build/index.js'

I feel something is wrong with the volumes in docker-compose.yml

Comment: As long as you use separate services in docker-compose for Django and Svelte they both can have the same workdir, since they are running in different docker containers.

The volumes are fine, your Dockerfile might need some tweaking. You are running npm install and npm ci which is redundant.

Comment: I feel that if I copy-paste what you put there. The volumes in docker-compose won't work in conjuntion with Django. I'll try nonetheless

Comment: As suspected, I got the error: "failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref XXXXXXX: "/package.json": not found"

Comment: Are you trying to put Django and Svelte into the same dockerfile?

Comment: not yet, I'm trying to run Svelte/Node on its own first and then once it is working, move it with Django but still doesn't work on its own. Again, I think it is something related to the volumes. Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42040317/cannot-find-module-for-a-node-js-app-running-in-a-docker-compose-environment

The error is "Error: Cannot find module '/app-frontend/build/index.js"
and I think it is related to this line " CMD ["node","build/index.js"]"