# access data volume of node modules outside docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, node-modules

I have docker setup for a node.js web service which creates a data volume for node modules like this:

```
  volumes:
       - ./service:/usr/src/service
       - /usr/src/service/node_modules
```

The solution with data volume works fine. But using a data volume, the `node_modules` are not accessible or visible in **my host** (*not container*) which creates other restrictions. For example: I can not run tests in `web-storm` as they expect `node_modules` to be present.

Is there any alternative solution other than using data volume to mount node modules which also allows to access them on host?

The docker file looks like:

```
FROM node:6.3.1-slim

ARG NPM_TOKEN
ARG service
ENV NODE_ENV development

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install build-essential git-core python-dev vim

# use nodemon for development
RUN npm install --global nodemon

COPY .npmrc /root/.npmrc

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/$service
RUN mkdir -p /modules/$service/
COPY sources/$service/package.json /modules/$service/package.json
RUN cd /modules/$service/ && npm install && rm -f /root/.npmrc && mv /modules/$service/node_modules /usr/src/$service/node_modules

WORKDIR /usr/src/$service
COPY sources/$service /usr/src/$service

ENV service=${service}

COPY start_services.sh /root/start_services.sh
COPY .env /root/.env
COPY services.sh /root/services.sh

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/root/start_services.sh"]
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/root/services.sh"]
CMD /root/start_services.sh
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker-compose: node\_modules not present in a volume after npm install succeeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30043872/docker-compose-node-modules-not-present-in-a-volume-after-npm-install-succeeds)

Comment: its not. Because i am using the solution from the post you mentioned. But as I wrote, the real problem at the end I have is that i do not have access to node modules on my host machine because of data volume.

Comment: Apologies. That wasn't immediately clear to me. I see what is going on now.

Answer (score 0):

Specify node_modules as follows:

```
volumes:
  - .:/usr/src/service/
  - /usr/src/service/node_modules
```

Comment: I do that already. Sorry forgot to mention that. Updated that part in the question.

Comment: @RajatArora Mmm okay. What does your Dockerfile look like?

Comment: I updated the question with my docker file. Thank you for taking the time to help.

Comment: @RajatArora sure. It seems in the Dockerfile you're copying over the `sources/service` directory and then syncing the volume `./service`. Should one of those be changed to match the other? Not sure from where things are being ran, but that's something to check (check simple things first).