# I/O error when trying to remove directory in docker build

Tags: docker, buildkit

I have this Dockerfile in which have some folders I want to remove and I can't use `dockerignore` file in that scenario.
In order to remove these folder I'm running the following line :

```
RUN find . -type d \( -name "pipelines" -o -name ".git" \) -exec rm -rf {} + || true
```

I'm using buildkit to build the image and I'm getting the following error:

```
#7 0.300 rm: can't remove '/usr/src/code/.git/hooks': I/O error
#7 0.300 rm: can't remove '/usr/src/code/.git/info': I/O error
#7 0.300 rm: can't remove '/usr/src/code/.git/logs/refs/heads': I/O error
#7 0.301 rm: can't remove '/usr/src/code/.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin': I/O error
#7 0.301 rm: can't remove '/usr/src/code/.git/objects/pack': I/O error
#7 0.301 rm: can't remove '/usr/src/code/.git/refs/heads': I/O error
```

When I run the same line multiple files I see that eventually all the .git files are getting removed but I don't think that is the correct way to do it.

I tried to remove some folders when building docker image but I'm getting I/O error.
The build is running in a Linux VM.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sudden I/O errors with docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68845635/sudden-i-o-errors-with-docker-compose)

Comment: no, unfortunately

Comment: Remember that, due to Docker's layer system, the content is still going to be part of the image and still taking up space, even if it's not directly visible in the container filesystem.  Would including `.git` in a `.dockerignore` file be more effective?

Comment: I can’t do that because the `.git` folder is in the base image