# Docker image working with docker run but not with docker-compose up

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, gatsby

I have a `gatsby` docker image which works as expected when run with `docker run`, but when I run it with `docker-compose up` I get the following error:

```
There was a problem loading the local develop command. Gatsby may not be installed in your site's "node_modules" directory. Perhaps you need to run "npm install"? You might need to delete your "package-lock.json" as well.
```

My `Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
FROM node:12-buster

RUN npm install --global gatsby-cli && gatsby telemetry --disable

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json /app/

RUN npm install --force

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["npm", "run", "develop"]
```

The compose file looks like this:

```
   frontend:
    build: frontend
    image: frontend
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - backend
```

Comment: When you tell "docker image which works as expected when run with docker run" is also mounting volume?

Comment: @matiferrigno yikes, I actually didn't mount the volume. When I drop it from the compose it works as well, so it is what's causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I belive that I saw the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The image will work fine when the code is in the context of build, because all commands RUN will be executed during docker build image process.

When you instance a image as you do on docker-compose, you are not running:

```
RUN npm install --force
```

because it was executed during build image time. No during launch container.

So, for solve your problem and considering how your image was built you need not to include a volume instead include your code as build context.

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  webapp:
    build:
      context: ./dir
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

Comment: Being brief, remove volume from you docker-compose and only include your code in context.

Comment: Another solution is to add a data volume as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30043872/docker-compose-node-modules-not-present-in-a-volume-after-npm-install-succeeds. So adding `/app/node_modules` to the volumes also works.

Comment: Exactly, it is because the npm_modules has already installed and you don't need npm install. It breaks a little the docker filosofy of "reborn" but is ok for agilize local development.

Comment: Adding `node_modules` as an anonymous volume causes Docker to consider that directory user data; you will never ever get any updates to that directory.  Removing the `volumes:` entirely as suggested here and using the code actually built into the image is better practice.