# How to run Angular project on Docker container?

Tags: node.js, angular, docker

I'm trying to run Docker services, one of them is angular services described below:

Dockerfile-angular:

```sh
FROM node:14
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN mkdir /youngtalentreturn
COPY ./venv_youngtalentreturn_frontend/project /youngtalentreturn/
RUN npm cache clean --force
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3000 4200
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
angular:
container_name: youngtalentreturn_angular_ctnr
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile-angular
restart: unless-stopped
volumes:
  - ./venv_youngtalentreturn_frontend/project:/usr/src/app
depends_on:
  - postgres
  - django
ports:
  - 3000:3000
  - 4000:4200
networks:
  - youngtalentreturn-ntwk
```

But throws an error:

```
youngtalentreturn_angular_ctnr | 
youngtalentreturn_angular_ctnr | > project@0.0.0 start /usr/src/app
youngtalentreturn_angular_ctnr | > ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
youngtalentreturn_angular_ctnr | 
youngtalentreturn_angular_ctnr | sh: 1: ng: not found
youngtalentreturn_angular_ctnr | npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
youngtalentreturn_angular_ctnr | npm ERR! syscall spawn
youngtalentreturn_angular_ctnr | npm ERR! file sh
youngtalentreturn_angular_ctnr | npm ERR! errno ENOENT
youngtalentreturn_angular_ctnr | npm ERR! project@0.0.0 start: `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0`
youngtalentreturn_angular_ctnr | npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
youngtalentreturn_angular_ctnr | npm ERR! 
youngtalentreturn_angular_ctnr | npm ERR! Failed at the project@0.0.0 start script.
youngtalentreturn_angular_ctnr | npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
youngtalentreturn_angular_ctnr | npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
youngtalentreturn_angular_ctnr | 
youngtalentreturn_angular_ctnr | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
youngtalentreturn_angular_ctnr | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-07-26T15_48_26_330Z-debug.log
```

Could anybody help me, please?

Comment: Because you are mounting over _/usr/src/app_ the _node_modules_, created by `npm install` in your Dockerfile, is also overwritten. You should create an [`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) that does `npm install` then `npm start`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker-compose: node\_modules not present in a volume after npm install succeeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30043872/docker-compose-node-modules-not-present-in-a-volume-after-npm-install-succeeds)

Comment: How docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile-angular should they be ?

Comment: I'd generally recommend a path that deletes the `volumes:` instead, so you're running the code that's actually built into the image.  Make sure the `WORKDIR` and the destination of the `COPY` match; the easiest way to do this is to put `WORKDIR` first and then `COPY package.json .` with the current directory as the destination.

Comment: Yes indeed, if you want to make something for a "fixed" environment, then  it would be best to follow the advices of @DavidMaze. Now if you want a "lively" feedback as you develop on that application, then the duplicated answer might be a good hint on how to approach it.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the following Dockerfile code for your angular project

Get your `appname` from the `package-lock.json` file of you angular project

```
# Stage 1
FROM node:latest as node
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build  --prod
# Stage 2
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=node /app/dist/{app-name} /usr/share/nginx/html
```