# Cannot find module @angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json during docker-compose up

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, docker-compose

I found many answers online to the exception *Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json*, among which adding `@angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1102.9 --force` , but none worked in my case.

### Problem

Running an Angular application using docker-compose: after building the application, the error below occurs when running `docker-compose up`; **note**, the app compiles successfully when running `docker run <image>`, but I need it to work with Docker Compose.

```
defuse-ui         | An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json'
defuse-ui         | Require stack:
defuse-ui         | - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/node-modules-architect-host.js
defuse-ui         | - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/index.js
defuse-ui         | - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js
defuse-ui         | - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/serve-impl.js
defuse-ui         | - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/export-ref.js
defuse-ui         | - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/index.js
defuse-ui         | - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/json-schema.js
defuse-ui         | - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js
defuse-ui         | - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js
defuse-ui         | - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/init.js
defuse-ui         | - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
defuse-ui         | See "/tmp/ng-nVUdCb/angular-errors.log" for further details.
defuse-ui exited with code 127
```

### Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.16.1

WORKDIR /app

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json /app/package.json

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@11.2.9 @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1102.9 --force
RUN npm install

COPY . /app

CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200
```

`package.json`, `package-lock.json` and other files are accessible at https://github.com/radon-h2020/radon-defuse/tree/905d7a339a31bc68dbd9b7a5258b5e9b19e65c68 [release 1.0.0](https://github.com/radon-h2020/radon-defuse/releases/tag/1.0.0)

Versions:

- Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701
- docker-compose version 1.29.2, build unknown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of trials, I finally found a solution on this useful [webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30043872/).
The `docker-compose.yml` has to be updated with a new volume pointing to the *node_modules*:

```
services:
  defuse-ui:
    build: ./defuse
    container_name: defuse-ui
    ports:
      - 4200:4200
    expose:
      - 4200
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules  # <-- Add this
      - ./defuse:/app # <!-- or remove this
```

A possible explanation, as described in the webpage is that

> when docker builds the image, the node_modules directory is created within the worker directory, and all the dependencies are installed there. Then on runtime the working directory from outside docker is mounted into the docker instance (which does not have the installed node_modules), hiding the node_modules you just installed.
> A workaround is to use a data volume to store all the node_modules, as data volumes copy in the data from the built docker image before the worker directory is mounted

Answer (score -1):

2 possible solutions:

1. Uninstall/remove node_modules and install again:

   npm install -g @angular/cli@11

   npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1102.9
2. Remove this line in docker-compose.yml:

   angular-ayaresa:
   build:
   context: build/angular
   ports:
   - "4200:4200"
   volumes:
   - ../source/angular:/usr/src/app/
   - /usr/src/app/node_modules/ // -- remove this line
   container_name: angular-ayaresa
   networks:
   - ayaresa-network

Comment: Regarding solution 1: the node_modules is not present in the container when is being built, therefore no need to remove it. Then, it already installs angular/cli and dev-kit.
As for solution 2, it seems to be copied-pasted from another solution on StackOverflow, since my docker-compose.yml does not have such code

Comment: Can you give your package.json?

Run: npm update -g @angular/cli

Comment: It should work!

1. npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular

2. npm rm -rf node_modules

3. Delete your package-lock.json

4. npm cache clean --force

5. npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@11.2.9

Comment: The package.json and all related files are at the link I provided in the response. It's an open-source project

Answer (score -1):

In **package.json**:

Instead of

```
"@angular/cli": "1.6.0",
```

change it to

```
"@angular/cli": "^1.6.0",
```

Or, in front of particular version of your local machine, add "^".

Then run this command:

```
npm update

npm update -g @angular/cli
```