# Vue 2 build with docker - sh: vue-cli-service: not found

Tags: docker, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli

I want to build a vue 2 app with docker, but got `sh: vue-cli-service: not found` error.
For serve, I have another docker files and everything there is fine, but in build I got this error!

Dockerfile

```
# build stage
FROM node:14.18.0-alpine as build-stage
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /var/www/html/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install -g @vue/cli
RUN npm i

COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
```

command: `docker-compose up -d`

Answer (score 1):

Are you using volumes for your `app` service in your docker-compose file?

I got a similar error on Vue.js 2 with Docker `npm run serve` was failing because the node_modules repository went missing in the Docker container. The root cause of it was that I am using [bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) to allow code hot reload in my development environment, which made Docker overwrite the node_modules repository after running `npm install -g @vue/cli`, which explains that cli couldn't be found.

I solved this by using a volume for the node_modules repository, [as explained by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30043872/docker-compose-node-modules-not-present-in-a-volume-after-npm-install-succeeds/32785014#32785014).