# PostgreSQL Error in Docker: How to Resolve?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm encountering a puzzling issue while trying to run PostgreSQL in a Docker container, and I could use some guidance. Whenever I attempt to start a PostgreSQL container, I encounter an error message that's preventing me from using the database.

The error message appears to be specific to PostgreSQL, and it's causing a hindrance in my development workflow. I've already tried several troubleshooting steps, including verifying my Docker configuration, checking for any conflicts in port mappings, and ensuring the PostgreSQL container image is up-to-date.

*docker-compose.yml*

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  # These are the configurations for our Node app
  # When Docker Compose starts this container it will automatically
  # use the Dockerfile in the directory to configure it
  app:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      # Our app does not work without our database
      # so this ensures our database is loaded first
      - postgres
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    volumes:
      # Maps our current project directory `.` to
      # our working directory in the container
      - ./:/usr/src/app/
      # node_modules workaround for volumes
      # https://stackoverflow.com/a/32785014
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules

  # This is the configuration for our PostgreSQL database container
  # Note the `postgres` name is important, in out Node app when we refer
  # to  `host: "postgres"` that value is mapped on the network to the
  # address of this container.
  postgres:
    image: postgres:14.1-alpine
    restart: always
    environment:
      # You can set the value of environment variables
      # in your docker-compose.yml file
      # Our Node app will use these to connect
      # to the database
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=urbanize
    ports:
      # Standard port for PostgreSQL databases
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      # When the PostgreSQL container is started it will run any scripts
      # provided in the `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory, this connects
      # our seed file to that directory so that it gets run
      - ./database-seed.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/database-seed.sql
```

**postgres connection string from env**

`POSTGRES_CONNECTION_STRING="postgresql://postgres:password@localhost:5432/urbanize"`

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:18

WORKDIR /app


COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5002

CMD ["yarn", "dev"]
```

[image]

**I have tried**

- killing the postgres service from the terminal
- loggin into docker
- changing the postgres config file to accept all ports

Answer (score 1):

This might not be an answer, but what happens if you try adding your DB connection string to the environment inside your app container like so?

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  # These are the configurations for our Node app
  # When Docker Compose starts this container it will automatically
  # use the Dockerfile in the directory to configure it
  app:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      # Our app does not work without our database
      # so this ensures our database is loaded first
      - postgres
    environment:
        DATABASE_URL=postgresql://postgres:password@localhost:5432/urbanize
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    volumes:
      # Maps our current project directory `.` to
      # our working directory in the container
      - ./:/usr/src/app/
      # node_modules workaround for volumes
      # https://stackoverflow.com/a/32785014
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules

  # This is the configuration for our PostgreSQL database container
  # Note the `postgres` name is important, in out Node app when we refer
  # to  `host: "postgres"` that value is mapped on the network to the
  # address of this container.
  postgres:
    image: postgres:14.1-alpine
    restart: always
    environment:
      # You can set the value of environment variables
      # in your docker-compose.yml file
      # Our Node app will use these to connect
      # to the database
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=urbanize
    ports:
      # Standard port for PostgreSQL databases
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      # When the PostgreSQL container is started it will run any scripts
      # provided in the `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory, this connects
      # our seed file to that directory so that it gets run
      - ./database-seed.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/database-seed.sql
```

Comment: compose command gives this error ```ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.app.environment contains an invalid type, it should be an object, or an array```

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to add `-`, so the line under environment should look like `- DATABASE_URL=postgresql://postgres:password@localhost:5432/urbanize` apologies

Comment: still the same error